# The best practice to make radio buttons respond to onClick events pragramatically within fragment (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

I`m looking for the best practice to make radio buttons respond to onClick events pragramatically within fragment (kotlin).

I came up with this solution, but i dont think that this is the best one. Here is a little snippet:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is RadioButton) {
            val checked = view.isChecked

            when (view.getId()) {
                R.id.option1 ->
                    if(checked) {
                        do something
                    }
                R.id.option2 ->
                    if(checked) {
                        do something
                    }
                R.id.option3 ->
                    if(checked) {
                        do something
                    }
                R.id.option4 ->
                    if(checked) {
                        do something
                    }
                R.id.option5 ->
                    if(checked) {
                        do something
                    }
            }
        }
    }

itemOptions = arrayOf(
        binding.option1,
        binding.option2,
        binding.option3,
        binding.option4,
        binding.option5
    )

itemOptions.forEach { x ->
        x.setOnClickListener{onRadioButtonClicked(x)}
    }
```

Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons have a Radio group, you need to implement setOnCheckedChangeListener on that

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ radioGroup: RadioGroup, checkedId: Int ->
    when(checkedId) -> {
       R.id.option1 -> //do something
       R.id.option2 -> //do something
       R.id.option3 -> //do something
       R.id.option4 -> //do something
   }
}
```